# Persisting with @Transient

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

In my POJO I have this:

```
@Transient
private int qtyMentee;
```

and in my DAO I have this query:

```
public List<Employee> findQtyMentee(){
    TypedQuery<Employee> query = (TypedQuery<Employee>) em.createNativeQuery(
        "select *, count(mentor_id) as qtymentee from employee group by id order by qtymentee asc" , Employee.class);
    Collection<Employee> employee  = (Collection<Employee>) query.getResultList();
    return (List<Employee>) employee;
}
```

When I try to get Qtymentee ever returns 0.

The annotation `@Transient` is wrong in this situation?

How can I get this value and show in my application?

OBS: I'm using Eclipselink.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but I need just in a specific situation this attribute.
If I remove it, Eclipselink returns me this error:
`ERROR 500: column "qtymentee" does not exist`.
in truth, qtymentee is a calculated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not supported.  Transient means it is not a field that is mapped or handled by JPA in anyway - it is excluded from being read or persisted from the database.  In this case, you are trying to push calculated data into the entity field, which would corrupt your cache of entities maintained by the context.

Hopefully you have mapped this as a 1:M (Say employee.mentees) and M:1 (say employee.mentor) in your object model.  If so, a simple size on the collection mapping will return the number of "mentee"s without the need of storing the value somewhere.

If you want the list ordered with the value returned directly, using JPQL (instead of SQL with the createNativeQuery method):

```
List<Object[]> list = createQuery("Select e, size(e.mentees) as qtymentee from Employee e order by qtymentee asc").getResultList();
```

If you haven't mapped the mentor_id field using reference mappings, you would need to resort to using a subqueries as I don't believe your SQL query posted would work.

If you must put it into a data object, you can use a constructor expression described here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor

It would look something like:

```
  createQuery("select new DAO(e.id, e.otherfield .., size(e.mentees)) from Employee e")
```

Answer (score 2):

Fields marked with @Transient will not be persisted. This means their value is not present in the database and using them in a query will have no effect. From the spec:

> This annotation specifies that the property or field is not
>   persistent.

[Javadoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)

Answer (score 0):

`@Transient` basically means `do not serialize me`. So `@Transient` prevents your field to be persisted. You should remove it.

Comment: Persisting is almost the same as serializing. Instead of sending the serialized data over message channel, it's sent to database.